# How to test java input and expected Output with Junit 4

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

## How to test Java input/output

Hello,

I have the following problem: I have a class, which handles the user interaction (Input/Output) and I need to write Junit4 tests for it.

The class I want to test looks something like this:

```java
package program;
// imports
public class UserInteraction {
    private Program program;

    private UserInteraction(){
        program = new Program();
    }

    // Menu display
    private void start() {
        while (!program.getProgramStarted) {
            String input = readInput();
            switch (input) {
            case "1":
                addUser();
                break;
            case "2":
                deleteUser();
                break;
            case "3":
                // ...
            default:
                System.err.println("Unknown option");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addUser() {
        // Output
        String username = readInput();
        program.addUser(username);
        System.out.println("User " + username + "added");
    }

    private void deleteUser() {
        // Output
        String username = readInput();
        program.deleteUser(username);
        System.out.println("User " + username + "deleted");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private String readInput() {
        return (new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        UserInteraction ui = new UserInteraction();
        ui.start();
    }

}
```

And the program class looks something like this:

```java
package program;
// imports
public class Program {
    // fields
    private User currentUser;
    private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
    // constructor

    public void addUser(String name) throws Exception {
        if (user.size() >= 6) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        int newID = user.size() + 1;
        user.add(new User(name, newID));
    }

    public String[] getALlUser() {
        int counter = 0;
        String[] userArray = new String[user.size()];

        for (User s : user) {
            userArray[counter++] = s.toString();
        }
        return userArray;
    }
}
```

Now, for example, I want to test, if the following Input is handled correctly:

```
1
John
=> User John added
```

For this purpose I wrote a Junit test that looks like this:

```java
package tests;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;

import program.*;

public class UserInteractionTest {

    private final InputStream originalIn = System.in;
    private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
    private Program program;

    @After
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setIn(originalIn);
        System.setOut(originalOut);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
        String input = "1\nJohn\n";
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent)); // Leitet System.out um

        program = new Program();
        try {
            program.main(null);
        } finally {
            System.setIn(originalIn);
        }
        String expectedOutput = "User John added";
        assertTrue("Output not found", outContent.toString().contains(expectedOutput));
    }

}
```

The input ("1\n") is made, however after that, no input is inserted, so the test hangs.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Or, perhaps a better way to test/validate the input/output of my Java program?

Thanks in advance!

I tried various modifications to the input Stream, like using `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n`, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Directly invoking the `main` method and expecting the entire flow to happen on its own is not essentially unit testing. Unit tests are written to test/verify the smallest piece of executable code (units) in an isolated manner. Meaning that you test every flow in a method individually separating it from the external behaviors. This isolation is commonly done using test doubles ([mocks](https://site.mockito.org/))

I suggest you understand the fundamentals right by referring to the official documentations and other resources available